# Skip while inserting if object with the same property value already exists

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

so, I think this should be quite easy, but I have been on this for hours, and I am unable to find a solution.

I created a sign up; the signup button has a function that takes the value of the email address and runs a for loop on all objects to check if the value already exists. If it exists, it should say "You already have an account" and stop, and if it doesn't exist, it should go ahead and push the array into the object.

However, it currently goes over each one of the array elements, instead of only checking for the typed value.

The code below:

```
let usersObj = [
{
    firstName: "James",
    age: 22,
    username: "James@gmail.com",
    password: "codity"
},
{
    firstName: "Ellen",
    age: 32,
    username: "Ellen@gmail.com",
    password: "laura" 
},
{
    firstName: "Lynn",
    age: 16,
    username: "Lynn@gmail.com",
    password: "chicken"   
},
```

];

```
$('#signUpSubmitBtn').on('click', function() {
    getUserSignUpData();
})
;
function getUserSignUpData() {
    let signUserName = $('#signUserName').val()
    let signUserAge = $('#signUserAge').val()
    let signUserEmail = $('#signUserEmail').val()
    let signUserPassword = $('#signUserPassword').val()

    for(i = 0; i < usersObj.length; i++) {
       if(signUserEmail == usersObj[i].username) {
        console.log('You already have an account!')
       } else{
        usersObj.push(
            {firstName: signUserName, age: signUserAge, username: signUserEmail, password: signUserPassword});
        console.log(usersObj);
       }
```

```js
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

let usersObj = [
    {
        firstName: "James",
        age: 22,
        username: "James@gmail.com",
        password: "codity"
    },
    {
        firstName: "Ellen",
        age: 32,
        username: "Ellen@gmail.com",
        password: "laura" 
    },
    {
        firstName: "Lynn",
        age: 16,
        username: "Lynn@gmail.com",
        password: "chicken"   
    },
];

console.log(usersObj)

// Log in

$('#loginSubmitBtn').on('click', function() {
    getUserLogin();
});


function getUserLogin() {
let username = $('#userEmail').val()
let password = $('#userPassword').val()

for(i = 0; i < usersObj.length; i++) {
    if(username == usersObj[i].username && password == usersObj[i].password) {
        console.log("Hi " + usersObj[i].firstName + ',' + ' You have succesfully logged in!');
        return
    } else if(username == usersObj[i].username && password !== usersObj[i].password) {
           console.log('Invalid user information');
           $('#loginErrorText').text('Invalid user information');
           return
           };
  }
  console.log("You don't have an account.");
  $('#loginErrorText').text("You don't have an account.");
};

// END Log in

// Sign Up

$('#signUpSubmitBtn').on('click', function() {
    getUserSignUpData();
});

function getUserSignUpData() {
    let signUserName = $('#signUserName').val()
    let signUserAge = $('#signUserAge').val()
    let signUserEmail = $('#signUserEmail').val()
    let signUserPassword = $('#signUserPassword').val()
    

    for(i = 0; i < usersObj.length; i++) {
       if(signUserEmail == usersObj[i].username) {
        console.log('You already have an account!');
       } else{
        usersObj.push(
            {firstName: signUserName, age: signUserAge, username: signUserEmail, password: signUserPassword});
        console.log(usersObj)
       };
    } ;
};



// console.log('You already have an account!');
//         $('#existingEmailWarningText').text('Account already exists!')


// Show / Hide Forms 

logInForm
signupForm

// Btn:
loginRef
signupRef

$('#logInForm').hide();

$('#loginRef').on('click', function() {
  $('#logInForm').show();
  $('#signupForm').hide();
});

$('#signupRef').on('click', function() {
    $('#logInForm').hide();
    $('#signupForm').show();
  });









// The END
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Link to style.css sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

    <section class="mt-4">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div>
                    <h3 class="text-primary">
                        Login
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="text-center">



        <div class="container">
            <!-- ROW 1 -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- COL 1 -->
                <div class="col">

                </div>
                <!-- COL 2 -->
                <div class="col">
                    <div id="logInForm">
                        <h3>Log in</h3>
                        <hr>
                        <form action="">
                            <!-- User Email -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="userEmail">Your email</label>
                                <input id="userEmail" class="form-control" type="email">
                            </div>
                            <!-- User Password -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="userPassword">Your password</label>
                                <input id="userPassword" class="form-control" type="password">
                            </div>
                            <!-- Login button -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="button" id="loginSubmitBtn" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Login</button>
                            </div>
                            <span class="text-danger mt-1" id=""><small id="loginErrorText"></small></span>
                            <small class="d-block">No account? <a id="signupRef" href="#">Signup Now</a></small>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- COL 3 -->
                <div class="col">

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- ROW 2 -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- COL 1 -->
                <div class="col">

                </div>
                <!-- COL 2 -->
                <div class="col">
                    <div id="signupForm">
                        <h3>Sign up</h3>
                        <hr>
                        <form action="">
                            <!-- User name -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="signUserName">Your name</label>
                                <input id="signUserName" class="form-control" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <!-- User age -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="signUserAge">Your birth date</label>
                                <input id="signUserAge" class="form-control" type="date">
                            </div>
                            <!-- User Email -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="signUserEmail">Your email</label>
                                <input id="signUserEmail" class="form-control" type="email">
                                <span class="text-danger" id=""><small id="existingEmailWarningText"></small></span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- User Password -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="signUserPassword">Your password</label>
                                <input id="signUserPassword" class="form-control" type="password">
                            </div>
                            <!-- Login button -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="button" id="signUpSubmitBtn" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Sign up</button>
                            </div>
                            <small>Already have an account? <a id="loginRef" href="#">Log in</a></small>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- COL 3 -->
                <div class="col">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Link to function.js sheet -->
    <script src="function.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should never be storing passwords in plain text. Let alone exposing it to client-side JS in a way like that.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov, yes, it was, thanks! I upvoted it, but it doesn't show as I don't have enough reputations! :/

Comment: @Terry, yup, thanks! This was mostly an exercise! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `for(...` loop should traverse your array of accounts to check whether (or not) target e-mail exists, and ***after that*** (if no duplicates exists) push the object into your array.

So, your code would rather look like:

```
let duplicateExists = false
for(i = 0; i < usersObj.length; i++) {
       if(signUserEmail == usersObj[i].username) {
         duplicateExists = true
         break
       }
}
if(!duplicateExists) usersObj.push({firstName: signUserName, age: signUserAge, username: signUserEmail, password: signUserPassword})
```

However, I would recommend the other way around - making use of [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (to check, whether some entry has duplicating `username`) and [shortcircuited condition check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) before pushing form data into resulting array:

```js
const usersObj = [{firstName:"James",age:22,username:"James@gmail.com",password:"codity"},{firstName:"Ellen",age:32,username:"Ellen@gmail.com",password:"laura"},{firstName:"Lynn",age:16,username:"Lynn@gmail.com",password:"chicken"}],
      dup = {firstName: 'Bill', age:48, username: 'Ellen@gmail.com', password: 'password'},
      nodup = {firstName: 'Bill', age: 48, username: 'Bill@gmail.com', password: 'password'},
      result = []

      const getUserSignUpData = (signupUserData) => {
        !usersObj.some(({username}) => 
          username == signupUserData.username) && result.push(signupUserData)
      }
      
getUserSignUpData(dup) // no entries are inserted due to duplicate username
getUserSignUpData(nodup) // nodup object is inserted as username is unique

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by looping through the array of objects each time with `some()`, and if no matches come up, pushing the new object to the array:

```js
let usersObj=[{firstName:"James",age:22,username:"James@gmail.com",password:"codity"},{firstName:"Ellen",age:32,username:"Ellen@gmail.com",password:"laura"},{firstName:"Lynn",age:16,username:"Lynn@gmail.com",password:"chicken"}];

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = (e) => {
  console.clear()
  e.preventDefault()
   let form = document.getElementById("form")
   
   if(!usersObj.some(el => el.username === form.username.value)){
       let newUserObj = {
          firstName: form.firstName.value,
          age: form.age.value,
          username: form.username.value,
          password: form.password.value,
       }
       usersObj.push(newUserObj)
       console.log("new user added", newUserObj)
   }else{
      console.log("user already exists")
   }
}
```

```css
input{position: absolute;left: 100px}
```

```html
<form id="form">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" /><br>
    Age: <input type="text" name="age" /><br>
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="James@gmail.com" /><br>
    Password: <input type="text" name="password" /><br>
    
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```